# ArrayItem equals atleast one term in another array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check to see if two arrays share at least one term in common for my program.

I'm not quite sure what the code is to compare two arrays, but here is what I have so far;

```
if ((modWikiKeyArray).equals(inputArray[0]))
{
   StringBuilder hyperlinkBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < modWikiKeyArray.length; i++)
   {
      hyperlinkBuilder.append(modWikiKeyArray[i]);  
   }
}
```

How would I compare the array modWikiKeyArray to inputArray just to check and see if inputArray[0] is equal to any term inside of modWikiKeyArray?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't work. If `inputArray[0]` appears multiple times in `modWikiKeyArray`, the code in the `if` statement will run multiple times. That's most likely not what you want. Also, even after you've found `inputArray[0]` in `modWikiKeyArray`, the loop will keep looking for more occurrences, which isn't efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
    for(int i=0;i<modWikiKeyArray.length;i++) {
        if(modWikiKeyArray[i].equals(inputArray[0])) {
            System.out.println("Match found");
        }
    }
```

**Note you need to override the equals() method of whatever array you are creating(Class of which array you are creating) .**

Comment: You can't override the `equals` method of an array (and you don't need to).

Comment: OMG!! equals() method of array.... Are you crazy? equals() method of class whose array you are making!!!

Comment: @Skippy thanks for the upvote but he was suggesting there is no need to overide .equals() method of an array. I mean seriously who says that. And if it is a custom class whose array you are making you must override .eaquls() method.

Comment: Have you ever tried to call `equals` on an array? Not an array element, but an actual array? Arrays themselves have `equals` methods. Your answer suggests that you need to override the `equals` method of `Thing[]` instead of `Thing`, which is impossible.

Comment: @Skippy Yes his answer is correct. His understanding is not. WHat do you think Arrays.asList(oneArray).contains(elementFromAnotherArray) does internally? Calls the .equals() method. Even array1AsSet.contains(o) boils down to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList` lets you build a list backed by an arbitrary array and use convenient Java Collections Framework features like the `contains` method:

```
Arrays.asList(oneArray).contains(elementFromAnotherArray)
```

If you want to see if the arrays have at least one element in common, you could build a `HashSet` out of one and loop over the other to try to find a common element:

```
boolean arraysIntersect(Object[] array1, Object[] array2) {
    Set array1AsSet = HashSet(Arrays.asList(array1));
    for (Object o : array2) {
        if (array1AsSet.contains(o)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This almost seems too complicated for the program I'm working with. I haven't even learned HashSets yet, but thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Skippy doesn't look like. See his comment on my post!

Comment: Just to make sure the above works, you also need to implement hashCode() for the element class.

Comment: @Neel: Yup. That's good practice whenever you implement `equals`, though, even if you expect your class never to be used in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your code snippet, it looks like you need to check the presence of inputArray[0] only, in which case the following is sufficient:

```
boolean exists = java.util.Arrays.asList(modWikiKeyArray).contains(inputArray[0]);
```

Alternatively, you might also want to use [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) from Apache commons-lang:

```
boolean exists = ArrayUtils.contains(modWikiKeyArray, inputArray[0]);
```

However, if I read the text of your question, it seems you want to find if modWikiKeyArray contains at least one item from inputArray. For this you may also use [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#rentainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) from the Collections API to perform a list intersecion and see if the intersection list is non-empty.

However, the most primitive is still Aniket's method. However, I will modify it to reduce unnecessary operations:

```
int i = modWikiKeyArray.length - 1;
MyObject inputElement = inputArray[0];
boolean found = false;
for(; i != 0; i--) {
    if(modWikiKeyArray[i].equals(inputElement)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```